# django model. Update status of choicefield

Tags: python, django

I was wondering how I can update a choice field with a condition. I need to update the status of a choice field from `RESERVED` to `PENDING` if `end_date < timezone.now()`.

I have tried the following piece of code, however, it did not work:

```
class ReservedRooms(models.Model):

    RESERVED = 'reserved'
    PENDING = 'pending'

    ROOM_STATUS = (
        (RESERVED, 'Reserved'),
        (PENDING, 'Pending')
    )

    status = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=ROOM_STATUS, default=RESERVED)
    reserved_by = models.ForeignKey(Visitor, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    reserved_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    begin_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField()



    def check_for_status(self):
        if self.end_date < timezone.now():
            self.status.update()
```

Comment: When is check_for_status() called? What does self.status.update() do?

Comment: `status` is a char field, what makes you think it has an `update()` method? Why not just `self.status = self.PENDING`?

Comment: Thank you daniel

Comment: ...and then probably `self.save()`